# What is the accepted practice for Django inter-app imports

Tags: python, django

It's quite easy to run into import problems with Django and apps which interact with each other.  My question is simple:

**What is the accepted process for minimizing circular imports or has anyone come up with an accepted coding standard to reduce these which they are willing to share.?**

I'm looking for good principles that can be standardized on.

Models

```
class Program(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")
```

vs

```
class Program(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('auth.Group', related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")
```

Views:

```
class ProgramDetailView(DetailView):
    """Detail view of the EEP Program"""

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Narrow this based on your company"""
        from apps.company.models import Company
        company = Company.objects.get(name="foo")
        return Program.objects.filter(company = company)
```

vs (which tends to cause the issues..

```
from apps.company.models import Company
class ProgramDetailView(DetailView):
    """Detail view of the EEP Program"""

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Narrow this based on your company"""
        company = Company.objects.get(name="foo")
        return Program.objects.filter(company = company)
```

The problem with this is that you tend to do a lot of imports all over the place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the years I standardized on some patterns, based on my observations on
how I develop web apps.

I don't know what are your standards about modularity and code re-use but the
following simple rules/patterns have helped me greatly with some fairly large
projects.

I have noticed that many of my models share some common attributes. For example
I prefer to use UUID's instead of simple auto increment integers, as primary keys.

So I have this abstract model.

```
class UUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, auto=True)  # There are many implementation of this on the web. Choose your favorite.

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Many of my models need the the concept of `activation`. So I have another abstract model,
similar to this:

```
class ActivatedModel(Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def activate(self, save=True):
        if self.is_active:
            raise Exception('Already activated')
        self.is_active = True
        if save:
            self.save()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

There are many other abstract models I use for tracking creation time and modification, or
if something is `finalized` and can't be further modified, etc.

All these abstract models live in the `core` app. This is how I call it.
Apart from the `core` app, I have a `tasks` app. The `tasks` app offers abstract
models that augments any interfacing I have to do with [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) which I use a lot.

The `tasks` app can import models from the `core` app, but not the other way around.

I have also an `mms` app, which handles Multimedia creation and transformations(thumbnails, etc).  The `mms` can import models from the previous apps. So the import relationship we have right now is this:  core -> tasks -> mms.

Every other app I create is specific to the current project I am working on and builds upon
the previous apps. So basically I try to have "**one way imports**" if you can call it that.

And I end up with models that look similar to this:

```
# models.py of an app called  "articles"

from core.models import UUIDModel, ActivatedModel
from tasks.models import ManagedTasksModel

class Article(UUIDModel, ActivatedModel, ManagedTasksModel):
    title = models.CharField()
    # blah...
```

If an app grows too big I "micromanage" the app by breaking the `models.py` module into
smaller modules **following** the above mentioned rules. I have found out that this covers
most of my needs.

I can't comment on class based views, because honestly I don't like them and it almost
always make me write more code instead of less. To each his own. I prefer to use helper
utility functions and make good use of things like [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS), inside
my view functions.

I hope my answer was within the context of your question.

EDIT: I just noticed your usage of `related_name` which I think misses the point of that option. See the following example:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender   = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_sent')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_received')
    body     = models.Textfield()
```

With the above model we can do this, which is very readable:

```
u1 = User.objects.get(...)
received = u1.messages_received.all()
```

... and it depicts the functional purpose of this relationship. So `related_name` is not
only used for having related names which are unique.

Answer (score 1):

## Regarding View Code

I don't think there is a high probability that the view code from app A would import the view code from app B in such a way that a circular import is caused.
If you happen to be using view code from another app B in app A's views, then that code should belong to a `views.py` file, but to an `utils.py` (or similar) file.

It is even more unlikely that the model code from app A would import the view code from  app B, so it's totally OK to use a top-level import for app A's model code in app B's view code.

## Regarding model code

As you mentioned however, having `ForeignKey` relationships between models from different apps can lead to circular imports.
Using the string notation for your `ForeignKey` addresses that challenge, and as the Django docs put it:

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself.

This also works for `ManyToMany` and `OneToOne` relationships.

## Regarding the existence of an accepted standard

I don't think there really exists one, but I figured that maybe looking at `django.contrib` apps would be relevant. They use model imports.

You might want to check out:

- [django.contrib.admin.models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py)
- [django.contrib.auth.models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py)
- [django.contrib.comments.models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/models.py)

Popular apps also use the same functionnality:

- [tastypie.models](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/models.py)
- [registration.models](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/registration/models.py)

You might also want to have a look at the source of `social_auth` for a variation on this:

- [social_auth.db.django_models.py](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/db/django_models.py)

I think that a general rule of thumb would be to use model imports when you can, but be ready to use string notation if needed.